# Bundling duplicate source file

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, requirejs, bundle, r.js

This is my index page (Index View).

```
define([
    'model/login'
    'view/login'
], function (LoginModel, loginview) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
         this.model = LoginModel;
      }
    someMethod: function() {
        new loginview();    
      }
    });
})
```

This is my another login page (Login View).

```
define([
    'model/login'
], function (LoginModel) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
         this.model = LoginModel;
      }
    });
})
```

Now I am creating one bundle using following configuration:

```
({
    appDir: "./",
    baseUrl: "./",
    mainConfigFile: './main.js',
    dir: './jsbuilt',
    //urlArgs: "v" + (new Date()).getTime(),
    //urlArgs: "v2", // "cache=v2",
    //fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|indexpage)\.js$/,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
//    wrap: {
//        start: "(function() {",
//        end: "}());"
//    },
    wrap: true,
    optimize: "uglify2",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        },
        {
            name: "basejs/indexpage",
            exclude: ['main']
        }
})
```

Now when I chack my bundle file. There is ' model/login'  code shows me twise. Becaues it is used in both view (eg. IndexView as well as LoginView). Means in my case I am seeing same code (LoginModel) duplicate. There for my bundle size increase unnecessary. How do I avoid this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to having common/shared code as a separate module in requirejs. So that you can exclude them from both indexview and loginview, and load it as separate module, with whichever loads first. and yes you have to make one more extra http request now. I normally have big chunk of common code and this approach works well for me.